# Using Javascript to change header menu when scrolling

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm currently working on changing a header menu when someone scrolls down. I got that to work, but now when someone scrolls back up at any point on the page, the header changes back. I want this to only happen from 855px from the top.

Just to clarify a bit more, there are two headers 'Header-row-a' and 'Header-row-b'. 'A' is originally showing when loading the page, when someone scrolls past 855px it changes to 'B'. When someone is past 855px+ and scrolls back up, it changes back to 'A', I only want that to happen when someone is back up between 0px and 855px.

Just to give you some more clarification, take a look at the site yourself: www.healthcoachfx.com and you'll see what I mean.

Let me know if any one of you can crack this one!

Many thanks in advance :)

**I used this Javascript and CSS:**

```js
var header_a = document.querySelector('#Header-row-a');
var header_b = document.querySelector('#Header-row-b');

var posY = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    if(this.pageYOffset > 855) {
        if(this.pageYOffset > posY) {
            header_a.style.transform = 'translateY(-81px)';
            header_b.style.transform = 'translateY(-81px)';
        } else {
            header_a.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
            header_b.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
        }
        posY = this.pageYOffset;
    }
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    header.fl-builder-content{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 30000;
}
#header-row-a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
}
.fl-row-content-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
#header-row-a, #header-row-b {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript

Comment: Can you add your relevant HTML as well, please?

Comment: Didn't use html. The site is build with 'BeaverBuilder' a Wordpress 'theme builder tool'. The header rows are standart BB theme functions, there are two, one with ID 'Header-row-a' the other one with 'Header-row-b'.

Comment: So in short: if scrolled longer than 855px, do `translateY(-81px)` - if above it, do `translateY(0)`? Do you even need to store `posY` then and account for whether user is scrolling up or down?

Comment: @Jeppe, yes - that is correct. Also, posY, no it wouldn't. How can I remove that? Javascript is still quite new for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do something as simple as this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    if (this.pageYOffset > 855) {
        header_a.style.transform = 'translateY(-81px)';
        header_b.style.transform = 'translateY(-81px)';
    } else {
        header_a.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
        header_b.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly it. As you'll see on the site it worked:)! Thank you @Jeppe!!

Comment: @Mitch Great! Feel free to accept this answer or ask if you have more questions (possibly in a new question). :-)